# Getting image from XML php

Tags: php, image

I am struggling with getting images from xml file

Let's say one image is stored in XML like this

```
<obrazok1>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA8Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NjIpLCBxdWFsaXR5ID0gMTAwCv/bAEMAAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAf ...</obrazok1>
```

My php code looks like this

```
dump($x->ponuka->obrazok1);
$data = base64_decode($x->ponuka->obrazok1);
dump($data);
$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

After this i get a typical icon of not known image ...

I think it might be a problem after using `base64_decode`.
It gives me:

[image]

Comment: Is the image type you get from the base64_decode a PNG file?

Comment: Are use sure it's not a JPEG? It looks like it is. Try sending image/jpeg content type instead of PNG.

Comment: Try to remove header and check PHP warnings. If you are showing the exact code: `$im` is undefined, maybe you mean `$image`.

Comment: Oh yes, i see there is: "..CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62) .." let me try your suggestions :) I tried to change header to header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); and then imagejpeg($image); but it is still the same :-\

Comment: If you open up the image in notepad or something, what is the first line of code?

Comment: If it is already an image, you dont use `imagecreatefromstring($data);`, you just decode the data and echo the contents (prepending the correct header and mime).

Comment: Oh maybe thats the problem. Instead of echoing it, is it possible to just save image ? I know it is but what function? Should i try move_uploaded_file?

Comment: you mean you want to get the image from xml and display it in php ?

Comment: What i am trying to do is import all adverts of real estates to database, so i want to save it in folder and insert in database its name ... Thats another funny way, how to get its name

Comment: I tried $data = base64_decode($x->ponuka->obrazok1);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($data); And still i can not see that image ...  This is that xml file http://www.sendspace.com/file/k2jxqz Thanks for replies guys

Comment: What if you just `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); echo base64_decode($x->ponuka->obrazok1)`?

Comment: I will try and let you know my friend:)

Comment: Guys i tried your solutions and nothing worked... vbo i tried it but still image is not resolved, can you please take a look at that xml file? Please.

Answer (score 0):

Is it your dump? Try commenting your dumps

```
// dump($x->ponuka->obrazok1); // comment this

// dump($data); // comment this
```

Comment: I tried this //dump($x->ponuka->obrazok1);
        $data = base64_decode($x->ponuka->obrazok1);
        //dump($data);
        $image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
        imagejpg($image); then i tried instead of imagejpg($image) this imagejpg($data); but still nothing worked ...  this is xml file http://www.sendspace.com/file/k2jxqz